# Basic property of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. If $X$ happens to be affine then is it true that the canonical morphism

$$X\to\mathrm{Spec}\;\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$$

is an isomorphism?.

Comment: I think that's what being an affine scheme is all about.

Comment: I suppose the definition of an affine scheme is that there is an (not necessarily canonical) isomorphism of  locally ringed spaces $X\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\;A}$ for a ring $A$ (then of course $A\cong\mathrm{Spec}\;\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Moreover, this property *characterizes* affine schemes among all *locally ringed spaces*. See [this MO comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89263/my-first-question-on-affine-schemes-in-algebraic-geometry/89265#comment229541_89265) for a proof sketch.

Comment: It seems that the link you provided above just contains the assertions with no proof. Can you clarify it a bit more for me? Thank you.